# Como construir um array com 2 subTotais para inserir os dados em um gráfico no ReactJS

Tags: javascript, array

Como montar um array que realiza a soma dos valores em 2 subtotais?

Utilizei o `.filter`, `.map` e `.reduce` para somar os valores mas não funciona com mais de uma categoria no mesmo array.

```js
var data = [
  { name: 'test1', day: '05/18', company:'1', total_price: 3 },
  { name: 'test4', day: '05/18', company:'1', total_price: 7 },
  { name: 'test2', day: '05/18', company:'2', total_price: 13.6 },
  { name: 'test3', day: '06/18', company:'1', total_price: 8 },
  { name: 'test3', day: '06/18', company:'2', total_price: 15 },
  { name: 'test4', day: '07/18', company:'2', total_price: 8 },
];

const sum = (a, b) => a+b;
const uniqueCategories = (array) => [...new Set(array.map(item => item.day))];
const chartData = uniqueCategories(data).map(day => [
  day,
  data
    .filter(item => item.day===day)
    .map(item => item.total_price)
    .reduce(sum)
]);
chartData.splice(0, 0, ["Day","$"])
console.log(chartData)
```

Retorno:

```
chartData= [
  ["Day", "$"],
  ["05/18", 23.6],
  ["06/18", 23],
  ["07/08", 8]
]
```

Esperava-se:

```
chartData= [
  ["Day", "1", "2"],
  ["05/18", 10, 13.6],
  ["06/18", 8, 15],
  ["07/08", 0, 8]
]
```

Comment: Leia [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta?cb=1). Você precisa incluir mais detalhes na sua pergunta, como: qual o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma longa de resolver esse problema é o seguinte:

1. crie um `array` com os `day` sem repetição
2. crie um `array` com os `company` sem repetição
3. com essas duas informações faça a interação de dias e dentro dessa interação as companhias alinhada, porque isso pode variar pelo que está na sua pergunta.
4. pronto o resultado esperado

Exemplo minimo:

```js
var data = [
  { name: 'test1', day: '05/18', company:'1', total_price: 3 },
  { name: 'test4', day: '05/18', company:'1', total_price: 7 },
  { name: 'test2', day: '05/18', company:'2', total_price: 13.6 },
  { name: 'test3', day: '06/18', company:'1', total_price: 8 },
  { name: 'test3', day: '06/18', company:'2', total_price: 15 },
  { name: 'test4', day: '07/18', company:'2', total_price: 8 },
];

//funções auxiliares
const groupBy = (array, callBack) => new Set(array.map(callBack));
const sumBy = (array, callBackFilter, callBackReduce) =>
  array
  .filter(callBackFilter)
  .reduce(callBackReduce, 0);
  
const createChart = (days, companys, data) => {  
  const chartData = [];
  chartData.push(['Day', ... companys]);
  for (let item of days) {
    const chartItem = [];
    chartItem.push(item);
    for (let com of companys) {
      chartItem.push(
        sumBy(
             data,  
             a => a.day === item && a.company === com, 
             (a, b) => a + b.total_price)
        );
    }
    chartData.push(chartItem);
  }
  return chartData;
}
//utilizando as funções
const days = groupBy(data, item => item.day);
const companys = groupBy(data, item => item.company);
const chartData = createChart(days, companys, data);

///*Exibição em um tabela*///
const table = document.getElementById('table');
for (let items of chartData) {
  var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
  var c0 = row.insertCell(0);
  var c1 = row.insertCell(1);
  var c2 = row.insertCell(2);
  c0.innerHTML = items[0];
  c1.innerHTML = items[1];
  c2.innerHTML = items[2];
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="table" width="50%">
  
<table>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, pesquisei muito, por dias... Muito obrigado mesmo, irei estudar bastante este código =)